# Windows 10 "media driver missing" on installation

Tags: drivers, sata, windows-10-preview, usb-3, ahci

[cross-post from [MS Answers community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/missing-media-driver-on-vanilla-windows-10-install/9136ba66-e200-49fb-8ce7-0ce8e7e10100?tm=1435759872130) as I doubt they will be able to help me there]

[Update: I just tested the Windows8.1 Iso: It works. This seems to be a bug with the Win10 Build]

Procedure:
Download ISO, put it on USB (tried both: dd and cp -r the contents). I booted using the UEFI boot.

- Disabling USB3 did not help.
- I have no CD/DVD-Drive, so this can't be the problem either.
- Last resort would be the SATA/AHCI ("F6") driver. I got the install disk and put the contents on another USB, the Windows installer finds the driver but it is NOT needed. Same thing goes for the driver I downloaded from the intel Website and for the one from the MB Vendor.

PC:

- Samsung 850 Evo SSD
- WD Green WD20EZRX
- AsRock B85M Pro4 with intel USB3.0 eXtensible Host (disabled for testing)

That's it for the relevant specs. I try to install Windows8.1 on it - currently downloading the iso from MSDevNet.

Is there a way to skip the error (media driver missing) screen - I mean, I cannot remove the USB stuff as suggested witout removing my MB, nor can I remove the inexisting CD/DVD-Drive ;-)
It may not be a relevant driver (the installer gives no info on what driver is missing, sadly) so I might just ignore the issue.
(Update: Cancel does cancel the whole installation process.

Build: 10130

Comment: Please clarify which screen you are talking about specifically.

Comment: The 'missing media driver' screen as I think I may not need the driver on the installation if it is some weird non-essential driver. Sadly the installer gives no info on what driver is needed - I will clarify my question accordingly

Comment: All I can say is that it isn't a missing USB 3.0 driver since Windows 10 supports booting from USB 3.0 devices which isn't the case for Windows 7.

Comment: Yep, I deactivated in the BIOS too and it didnt work still - so I ignored that too. After eliminating the CD/DVD Drive option only AHCI could be the problem though this driver I did not want (it loaded it but still it said that there were missing drivers)

Comment: Only needed once: Xeon 1231v3 as CPU and an MSI nVidia GTX970, but they are no media devices, others I do not have installed. The cancel button only cancels the whole installation

Comment: Latest (10130),will update accordingly

Comment: Win8.1 works - Updated question

Comment: Since W10 is still beta, there will be bugs.

Comment: Sure, I never denied this. But I assumed one could maybe workaround it.

Comment: try the latest build 10162 (http://winaero.com/blog/download-windows-10-build-10162-iso-images-for-clean-install/)

Comment: Yep, they fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build 10130 that you use is a bit old. You should try the latest Build 10162, which you [can get from here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso).

Comment: it wasnt there at the time I first tried it though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Used a microsd to usb adapter. Windows 10 install worked from usb using a sandisk adapter, but when the microsd card was put into a generic adapter, would get the driver missing error. Put the sd card back into the sandisk adapter and it would work again. Even recreating install media onto the sdcard via the generic adapter didnt help. It would boot, but then give the driver missing error when trying to install. Took the recreated sdcard and put it in sandisk adapter and it worked again.

Makes no sense and it appears that some generic usb drivers are missing. I guess if you are having issues installing from a usb device, try creating the install mefia on a different one and see if that works.

Comment: It's solved already - they pushed a new build which fixed that. Idk about the Windows10 release-build isos though.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  It explains the behavior but does not explain how to said problem.

Comment: This actually helped me - was getting this error as I was using a microsd card + usb adapter. Used a normal usb drive and it worked fine. +1 for that